# Why is the Send trait required inside my match block?

Tags: rust, lifetime, rust-tokio, rust-async-std

I think my question relates to [Rust Issue 57017](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/57017).

The following [code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=763546b5d17e24d004bdde464d9a4112) does not compile and produces `error: future cannot be sent between threads safely` due to `future created by async block is not 'Send'` originating in `async fn execute_fail`. On the other hand `async fn execute_work` compiles and has the same functions and logic as `execute_fail` but in a less elegant manner.

```
async fn stream() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    Ok(())
}

async fn process() {}

async fn execute_fail() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    match stream().await {
        Err(err) => {
            return Err(err);
        }
        Ok(()) => {
            process().await;
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}

async fn execute_work() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut is_success = false;
    match stream().await {
        Err(err) => {
            return Err(err);
        }
        Ok(()) => {
            is_success = true;
        }
    }

    if is_success {
        process().await;
    }
    Ok(())
}

async fn my_fn() {
    tokio::spawn(async {
        if let Err(err) = execute_fail().await {
            panic!("error here");
        }
    });

    tokio::spawn(async {
        if let Err(err) = execute_work().await {
            panic!("error here");
        }
    });
}
```

Gives:

```
error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src/lib.rs:39:5
    |
39  |     tokio::spawn(async {
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ future created by async block is not `Send`
    | 
   ::: /playground/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.11.0/src/task/spawn.rs:127:21
    |
127 |         T: Future + Send + 'static,
    |                     ---- required by this bound in `tokio::spawn`
    |
    = help: the trait `Send` is not implemented for `dyn std::error::Error`
note: future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
   --> src/lib.rs:15:13
    |
10  |     match stream().await {
    |           -------------- has type `Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>>` which is not `Send`
...
15  |             process().await;
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ await occurs here, with `stream().await` maybe used later
16  |         }
17  |     }
    |     - `stream().await` is later dropped here
```

I would like an explanation why `execute_fail` does not compile where as `execute_work` does. The compiler note `note: future is not` Send `as this value is used across an await` doesn't make sense to me as I don't see how any values are being used across an await.

Comment: `stream().await` is considered to be in use until the closing brace of the `match`, but you call `process().await` inside the `match`

Comment: Do you know why the compiler thinks that? I can understand the result of `stream().await` being inside `match` but not the actual future which should be resolved by the time the result is processed within the `match` clause.

Comment: The `stream().await` future is indeed resolved by the time `match` is actually processes. The problem is it overlaps `process().await`, and types must be `Send` to live "through" an `await`. Which `Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>` is not because `Box<dyn Error>` is not.

Comment: The problem is not `stream().await`, if you replace `stream()` by a non-async function you'll get the same error. The problem is that the lifetime of the `Result` (which is non-send) overlaps with `process().await`. Because a future can be resumed on a different scheduler (and thus thread) than it was suspended, values overlapping with an `await` call must be `Send`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like an explanation why execute_fail does not compile where as execute_work does.

When you `match stream().await` it essentially works as:

```rust
let v = stream().await;
match v {
   ...
}
```

So `v` is alive for the entirety of the match, meaning as far as the compiler is concerned its "life" overlaps with the `process().await` call. Values must be `Send` to live through an `await` call, as the coroutine may be resumed on a different thread than it was suspended.

Of note: the code here can be significantly simplified:

```rust
async fn execute_fail() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    if let Err(err) = stream().await {
        return Err(err);
    }
    process().await;
    Ok(())
}
```

or even

```rust
async fn execute_fail() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    stream().await?;
    process().await;
    Ok(())
}
```