# Different behavior between match and unwrap

Tags: rust, error-handling

I have done a small program, and it shows a weird behavior that I cannot explain.
I am using rodio crate to try out some audio stuff.

I have done two programs that, in my opinion, should give the same result.

The first one I use matches to handle errors:

```
let sink : Option<Sink> = match rodio::OutputStream::try_default() {
        Ok((_, handle)) => {
            match Sink::try_new(&handle) {
                Ok(s) => Some(s),
                Err(_e) => None,
            }
        },
        Err(_e) => None,
};
println!("{}", sink.unwrap().len());
```

In the last one, I have used unwrap instead.

```
let (_, handle) = rodio::OutputStream::try_default().unwrap();
let s = Sink::try_new(&handle).unwrap();
println!("{}",s.len());
```

The first one executes the print statement as expected, while the last one panics in the second unwrap.

It is very strange to me as soon as there is no error propagation, implicit conversions or other things that can explain that. The problem here is not related to the error itself but the difference between the two codes.

Comment: @trentcl that's not the issue here, the issue is that the version using unwrap fails while the version not using it succeeds, despite the two *seeming* equivalent.

Comment: Just an FYI, `Result` has `ok()` which converts into an `Optional`, with `Ok(x) -> Some(x)` and `Err(_) -> None`

Comment: @BallpointBen thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is one of *scoping* and an implementation detail of rodio: the one critical item here is `OutputStream::try_default()`, it doesn't really matter how you handle `Sink::try_new(&handle)` it'll always behave the same, not so `try_default`, if you match or `if let` it it'll work fine, if you `unwrap` it it'll fail.

But why would that be, the two should be equivalent. The answer is in the details of rodio, specifically of `OutputStreamHandle`:

```rust
pub struct OutputStreamHandle {
    mixer: Weak<DynamicMixerController<f32>>,
}
```

So an `OutputStreamHandle` (OSH thereafter) only holds a weakref to a `DynamicMixerController`, to which the `OutputStream` (OS thereafter) holds a strong reference.

This means the OSH only "works" as long as the OS is alive.

```rust
let (_, handle) = OutputStream::try_default().unwrap();
```

does not *name* the OS, so doesn't hold onto it, it's immediately dropped, the `Arc` is released and the OSH holds onto nothing, and the sink is unhappy.

How can the other one work then? Because

```rust
    if let Ok((_, handle)) = OutputStream::try_default() {
        let sink = Sink::try_new(&handle).unwrap();
        println!("match {}", sink.len());
    }
```

is really rather

```rust
{
    let _var = OutputStream::try_default();
    if let Ok((_, handle)) = _var {
        let sink = Sink::try_new(&handle).unwrap();
        println!("match {}", sink.len());
    }
}
```

so the `match`/`if let` itself is keeping the `Result` alive, which is a blessing here (but [causes issues just the next question over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69391809/why-is-the-send-trait-required-inside-my-match-block)).

Since the `Result` is kept alive, the tuple is kept alive, the `OutputStream` is kept alive, the `Arc` is kept alive, and thus the OSH has a working `mixer`, which the sink can make use of.

You can fix the issue of the second version by binding the `OutputStream` to a "proper" name e.g.

```rust
let (_stream, handle) = OutputStream::try_default().unwrap();
```

prefixing a name with `_` will create the binding for real, but will suppress the "unused variable" warning.

FWIW being careful around this sort of things is incredibly important around RAII types whose values you "don't need", most commonly mutexes protecting *code* as opposed to data:

```rust
let _ = m.lock().unwrap();
```

doesn't do anything, the mutex guard is not kept alive, so the lock is immediately released. In that case, you'd rather

```rust
let _lock = m.lock().unwrap():
```

or even better

```rust
let lock = m.lock().unwrap();
...
drop(lock);
```

Comment: Thank you. It was an amazing answer.